# How to create a split button when one button can be disabled with tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a split button with the use of Material UI components like `ButtonGroup` and `Button`: https://material-ui.com/components/button-group/#split-button.

The problem is the first button can be disabled and also show a tooltip when it's disabled. The recommendation is to wrap the button with `span`, but then it breaks the styling of the buttons. Is there any solution for this or I have to use custom styling for the buttons?

The code I use:

```
<ButtonGroup variant="contained" color="primary" aria-label="split button">
  <Tooltip title="You don't have permission to do this">
    <span>
      <Button disabled onClick={handleClick}>Send</Button>
    </span>
  </Tooltip>
  <Button onClick={handleToggle}>
    <ArrowDropDownIcon />
  </Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add style to span;

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) //same color used for disabled button
```

Comment: Styling is still a bit different and border radii aren't correct when you compare it with default styles: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-paper-wilg7

Comment: the style in material UI is as per their guidelines if we want to custom write it, copy add styles for default button and apply same for <span>

Comment: Ye, that's true. I tried to achieve this without writing custom styles or duplicating Material ones, but I guess this is just too specific issue.